# Set image slider height to the height of the smallest image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im using http://bxslider.com/ for a responsive image slider. The slider is currently setting the height to be the height of the largest image. I want to make it the height of the smallest image and cut off any excess for images that are larger than the smallest.

I tried `adaptiveHeight: true` ,but this results in the content below the slider moving around as the slider resizes. I tried to use css and the following almost worked.

```
.bx-wrapper, .bx-viewport {
    height: 300px !important;
}
```

The problem i had here was 300px looked perfect for my screen, but i have a responsive website so when i viewed this on a smaller screen there was a huge amount of white space below the image since 300px was far too big.

Comment: Use media queries to adjust the height for smaller screens.

Comment: you need to post ur html and if possible post code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have different screen resolutions for your app. Then use `@media` queries to change the CSS:

What exactly the below code does to your HTML:

1. The first thing is, each browser page will have its own view port size, or window size.
2. Media queries as based on the Window Size.
3. If your Window Size falls under a particular range, those styles get applied.
4. To make your BX Slider Responsive, based on the screen-size, we adjust the `height`.

```css
/* Default Style */
.bx-wrapper, .bx-viewport {
    height: 300px !important;
}
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    .bx-wrapper, .bx-viewport {
        height: 250px !important;
    }
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) {
    .bx-wrapper, .bx-viewport {
        height: 275px !important;
    }
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}
/**********
iPad 3
**********/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 5 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6+ ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S3 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S5 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}
```

I did it for the first two. Keep this as a template and you can test on different resolutions using the Chrome's Responsive Design tester in the Developer tools:

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

Comment: can you post it as a snippet

Comment: @Alex This is just a CSS, and doesn't require a snippet, really? But sure, will do it.

Comment: what exactly ur code will do? can u explain a little?

Comment: @Alex Sure, will do that. Writing the explanation. `:)`

Comment: @Alex Is the above detail okay?

Answer (score 0):

the slider sets the height  on `bx-viewport` through JS , in response to screen size(AKA responsively).

if you want to *force* an image size you could target `.bx-wrapper img`, but you need media queries otherwise you loose responsiveness.